# Convert code to Neon assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, simd, neon

I'm working on translating the code below into Neon Assembly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void sum(int length, int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, char *result)
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          int sum = (a[i] + b[i] + c[i] + d[i])/4;
          if (sum > threshold)
             result[i] = 1;
          else
             result[i] = 0;
      }
}
```

The actual code is an image binarization algorithm. The above code is just to demonstrate the idea and not to make simple things more complicate.

Comment: Can't you just run it through a compiler?

Comment: just turn on the switch on the compiler to generate assembly then translate that output to Neon assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward implementation. Note that we convert the divide and threshold test into just a test against `threshold * 4` (in order to eliminate the divide):

```
void sum(const int n, const int32_t *a, const int32_t *b, const int32_t *c, const int32_t *d, int32_t *result)
{
   const int32_t threshold4 = threshold * 4;
   const int32x4_t vthreshold4 = { threshold4, threshold4, threshold4, threshold4 };
   const uint32x4_t vk1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
   {
      int32x4_t va = vld1q_s32(&a[i]);    // load values from a, b, c, d
      int32x4_t vb = vld1q_s32(&b[i]);
      int32x4_t vc = vld1q_s32(&c[i]);
      int32x4_t vd = vld1q_s32(&d[i]);

      int32x4_t vsum = vaddq_s32(va, vb); // sum values form a, b, c, d
      vsum = vaddq_s32(vsum, vc);
      vsum = vaddq_s32(vsum, vd);

      uint32x4_t vcmp = vcgtq_s32(vsum, vthreshold4);
                                          // compare with threshold * 4
      int32x4_t vresult = (int32x4_t)vandq_u32(vcmp, vk1);
                                          // convert result to 0/1
      vst1q_s32(&result[i], vresult);     // store result
   }
}
```

Notes:

- completely untested code - may need further work
- `result` has been changed to `int32_t *` - it's not hard to pack down to `uint8_t` but it adds a lot of complexity to this initial example so I thought I'd keep it simple for now
- `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `result` all need to be 16 byte aligned
- `n` needs to be a multiple of 4
- sum of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` needs to fit within 32 bit signed int
- `threshold * 4` needs to fit within 32 bit signed int

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Because the source is grayscale image, I need to load uchar into int32x4_t value. I'm thinking of using int32x4_t input = vshrn_n_u32(source, 24) // source is uint8_t. Would you please tell me how you do the pack down?

Comment: To pack down to 8 bits you need to take 4 x 4 x 32 bit vectors and use vmovn_xxx or vpadd_xxx instructions to pack first to 2 x 8 x 16 bit vectors and then again down to a single 16 x 8 bit vector.

Comment: Thanks @paul-r. Actually, we are packing from q (128 bit) to d (64 bit) register, so I think it should be 2x32x4 -> 2x16x4 -> 8x8 vector. I still working on implementing this (I'm totally new to Neon so it took me so much time)

Comment: @PaulR - Is there anything that can be done to speed up these initializations: `int32x4_t vthreshold4 = { threshold4, threshold4, threshold4, threshold4 }` and `uint32x4_t vk1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }`. I have a function on the critical code path that has to do it multiple times due to the algorithm specification (BLAKE2 cryptographic hash).

Comment: @jww: the compiler should be smart enough to hoist constants such as this out of any enclosing loop, even if it's from within an inline function - have you checked the generated code ? Failing that, you could just pass the initialised constants into the function as parameters.